# Importing JPG, JPEG, and PNG images from a folder to an Excel worksheet

Tags: beginner, vba, excel, image, file-system

As I am a novice, I was keen to solve the task, so now I want to optimize the code.

```
Sub AddOlEObject()

    Dim mainWorkBook As Workbook

    Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
    Sheets("SingleProfile").Activate
    Folderpath = "C:\Users\sandeep.hc\Pics"
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    NoOfFiles = fso.GetFolder(Folderpath).Files.Count
    Set listfiles = fso.GetFolder(Folderpath).Files
    For Each fls In listfiles
       strCompFilePath = Folderpath & "\" & Trim(fls.Name)
        If strCompFilePath <> "" Then
            If (InStr(1, strCompFilePath, "jpg", vbTextCompare) > 1 _
            Or InStr(1, strCompFilePath, "jpeg", vbTextCompare) > 1 _
            Or InStr(1, strCompFilePath, "png", vbTextCompare) > 1) Then
                 counter = 29
                 counter1 = counter1 + 1

                Call insert(strCompFilePath, counter, counter1)
                'Sheets("SingleProfile").Activate
                counter1 = counter1 + 17
            End If
        End If
    Next
mainWorkBook.Save
End Sub

Function insert(PicPath, counter, counter1)
'MsgBox PicPath
    With ActiveSheet.Pictures.insert(PicPath)
        With .ShapeRange
            .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            .Width = 875
            .Height = 300
        End With
        .Left = ActiveSheet.Cells(counter, counter1).Left
        .Top = ActiveSheet.Cells(counter, counter1).Top
        .Placement = 1
        .PrintObject = True
    End With
End Function
```

**Based on Comments Optimized code**

```
Sub AddImage2()
Dim rgTarget As Range
Dim RowI As Long, ColumnI As Long

    Folderpath = "C:\Users\sandeep.hc\Pics"
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    NoOfFiles = fso.GetFolder(Folderpath).Files.Count
    Set listfiles = fso.GetFolder(Folderpath).Files
    For Each fls In listfiles
       strCompFilePath = Folderpath & "\" & Trim(fls.Name)
        If strCompFilePath <> "" Then
            If (InStr(1, strCompFilePath, "jpg", vbTextCompare) > 1 _
            Or InStr(1, strCompFilePath, "jpeg", vbTextCompare) > 1 _
            Or InStr(1, strCompFilePath, "png", vbTextCompare) > 1) Then
    RowI = 29
    ColumnI = ColumnI + 1
    Set rgTarget = Cells(RowI, ColumnI)
    Application.ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture strCompFilePath, False, True, rgTarget.Left, rgTarget.Top, 875, 400
    ColumnI = ColumnI + 17
    End If

End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will summarize what I said before (and add a few new ones):

- Use `Option Explicit` at the top of your module. It helps you to prevent mistakes and forces you to declare the variables
- instead of `Instr` use `Right` as in `If Right(strCompFilePath,4)=".jpg"`
- rename `counter` and `counter1` so it is clear what they are (row and column indices)
- Declare `insert` as a Sub and not a Function.
- instead of passing the row and column index to the `insert` function/sub and then using the ActiveSheet pass the cell as a Range to the `insert` function/sub. (Instead of Activesheet you can use `cell.Worksheet` to get the right sheet)
- possibly rename `insert` so you don't confuse it with `Pictures.insert`
- add the option `savewithfile := true` to the `Pictures.Insert` method so the pictures will stay in the file even if you send it somewhere.
- as it is now, you don't really need `NoOfFiles` and `mainWorkBook`
- instead of the FileSystemObject I would use `Dir`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba) for more on that.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed help to understand and improve the code i have tried to consider all the points and i have used the method shapes.Addpicture instead of .Insert

Answer (score 4):

Be sure to avoid things like `.Activate` - it just slows the code down by needing to fiddle with the spreadsheet while doing everything else behind the scenes. There's a [good question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) addressing this.